# How do I remove black marks caused by ironing?

Tags: clothing, stain

[image]

How do I remove such black marks caused by ironing?

Comment: It is unclear from the picture if the black mark is a burn mark (burned t-shirt, not removable) or dirt from the iron (older burns transferred from iron to t-shirt). Can you clarify for us? Try some hydrogen peroxide, followed by some local hand wash.

Comment: Not to *remove* it, but to prevent some spots, clean the sole of the iron with very fine steel wool. **Be very careful using it: steel wool is flammable and pieces in the iron could cause a short circuit.**

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by using a solution of **water and lemon juice**. Mix equal parts lemon juice and cold water in a bowl and then use a clean white cloth to sponge the solution onto the affected area. Let it sit for **10 minutes** before rinsing it off with warm water. This should help to remove any iron marks from your clothes.